# Is it safe to pass a pointer to a UTF-8 array to String(SByte*)

Tags: c#, .net, string

From msdn:

```
public String(char* value)
```

Initializes a new instance of the String class to the value indicated by a specified pointer to an array of Unicode characters.

```
public String(sbyte* value)
```

Initializes a new instance of the String class to the value indicated by a pointer to an array of **8-bit signed integers**.

So the first ctor accepts (UTF-16). But can the signed integers of the second method be the UTF-8 encoding of the string?

Reflector or dotPeek don't tell anything:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall), SecurityCritical, CLSCompliant(false)]
public extern unsafe String(sbyte* value);
```

As this test shows, UTF8 cannot be passed:

```
        string s0 = "string test lé lù $§";
        Console.WriteLine(s0);

        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s0);
        fixed (byte* p = bytes)
        {
            string s1 = new String((sbyte*)p);
            Console.WriteLine(s1);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you shouldn't pass a UTF-8 array to this particular constructor because it will interpret the array using the default code page (for example, Windows 1252). From [MSDN Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.string(v=vs.110).aspx#Creating_Strings):

> From a pointer to a signed byte array. Either the entire array or a specified range can be used to initialize the string. The sequence of bytes can be interpreted by using the default code page encoding, or an encoding can be specified in the constructor call.

If you have a pointer to a UTF-8 array, then use the [alternate constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9d876whe(v=vs.110).aspx) that accepts an Encoding, and pass it Encoding.UTF8:

```
string s1 = new String((sbyte*)p, 0, bytes.Length, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert a byte array to a char array use the Encoding class:

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetChars()
```

See also `GetDecoder`:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding.getdecoder(v=vs.110).aspx